# Eclipse not finding compiled JSP source

Tags: eclipse, jsp, exception

I have an inconvenience debugging JSP files when an exception is thrown in the compiled JSP file.  Clicking the link displayed on the console can not locate the source file. The source can be navigated to if the exception is thrown in a java file.  Any ideas how to permanently attach the source?

See x.java:64 below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.OwHIN.x_jsp._jspService(x_jsp.java:64)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't. The compiled .class file exists only when the running server creates it, where the server creates it, and that's what contains all of the source mapping information to get you back to the right part of the right source file (as part of JSR-45). Basically, the only time you have access to it is when the server's running and has loaded the JSP's equivalent class, so halting on the `NullPointerException` is as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm not concerned about the cause of the null pointer but that the source of the compiled JSP file that cannot be found.  I can explain if better by stating the problem is not the compiled .class but the generated .java from the compilation of a JSP.  Tomcat takes JSP source in and produces an equivalent java file with.  It then compiles the resulting .java file to produce the .class which is executed at runtime as stated.  JSP -> java source -> .class.  It’s the generated Java source file that cannot be located.

Comment: It appears that once I attach the source at run time it remains attached even after leaving eclipse.  I’m looking for a way to add the fold which contains all the generated java source to the source lookup path in eclipse

Comment: The context menu in the Debug view should allow you to change the stratum when you've paused the VM, to show the Java source instead of the original JSP. Again, only when the server is active.

Comment: thank you for the help. see my answer below.  I found as solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for permanently attaching the source with the class file.
Since .class file is been created during runtime.

The concerned issue is NullPointerException.

This is Runtime exception caused when the object is not initialized and is being referenced somewhere.The somewhere line number that is 64 and within the following path.

```
{$tomcat}/work/catalina/localhost/<#modulename#>/<#JSPName#>_jsp.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the source and added the folder as a source folder.  Now when I click the exception source link in the console window it takes me to the foul code that caused the issue.

...\My Work space Folder.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\MyWebProject\org\apache\jsp\MyWebRoot

Comment: Just a heads up.  Be cautious as to which file you are editing when using the compiled jsp java source.  I've made changes in the wrong file as the look very similar and wasted time debugging code that wasn't compiled to the .class as well as losing the changes